# How to add the total + 1 in the text span each time a notification using vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <span v-if="total > 0" class="badge" id="total">{{ total }}</span>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.initialMount()
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['total'])
        },
        methods: {
            initialMount() {
                Echo.private('App.User.' + window.Laravel.authUser.id).notification((notification) => {
                     const a = $('#total').text()
                     const b= parseInt(a) + 1
                     $('#total').text(b)
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

My modules is like this :

```
import { set } from 'vue'
import notification from '../../api/notification'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

const state = {
    total: 0,
}

const getters = {
    total: state => state.total
}

const actions = {
    getNotificationList ({ commit,state })
    {
        notification.getList(
            data => {
                const notifications = data
                commit(types.GET_NOTIFICATION,{ notifications });
            },
            errors => {
                console.log(errors)
            }
        )
    }
}

const mutations = {
    [types.GET_NOTIFICATION] (state, { notifications }) {
        state.total = notifications.length
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

===================================================================

I want every notification, the notification number incremented by 1

My above code works, but it still using jquery

I want change it using vue.js

How can I do it?

Comment: what is the error, it looks correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit action into the sucess callback of Echo, but first you have to define mutation:

```
const mutations = {
    [types.GET_NOTIFICATION] (state, { notifications }) {
        state.total = notifications.length
    },
    inc (state) {
      state.total++
    }
}
```

And then, you can commit action

```
methods: {
    initialMount() {
        Echo.private('App.User.' + window.Laravel.authUser.id).notification((notification) => {
          // Make sure you have imported store
          store.commit('inc')
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: On the console exist error : `ReferenceError: store is not defined`

Comment: As I mentioned you have to import your vuex store

Comment: Sorry I am on phone now, would be able to write later

Comment: You have to import whole vuex store object, and It has to be exported before.